# Websrapping from Reuters using PHP, how do I correctly identify the elements I wish to select

Tags: php, web-scraping

With this code (below) i can return the current price of AAPL/Apple. How do i modify this to return the previous close for example.

```
$ticker = "aapl";

$url  = "http://reuters.com/finance/stocks/overview?symbol=";
$newURL = $url.$ticker;
$result = file_get_contents($newURL);

$nyArr1     = explode('font-size: 23px;">', $result);
if ($nyArr1[1]) {
    $nyArr2 = explode("</span>", $nyArr1[1]);
    if ($nyArr2[1]) {
        $nyPrice = $nyArr2[0];
    }
}
```

Site link: https://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/overview/AAPL.O

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to parse a HTML document with PHP, like this :

```
$ticker = "aapl";
$baseUrl  = "http://reuters.com/finance/stocks/overview?symbol=";
$url =  $baseUrl.$ticker;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);

echo "First value :". $finder->query('//*[@id="headerQuoteContainer"]/div[1]/div/span[2]')->item(0)->nodeValue."<br/>";
echo "Second value :". $finder->query('//*[@id="headerQuoteContainer"]/div[3]/div[1]/span[2]')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

I have used [DomXPath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) but it is not mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following to get the required content. In case you need another value, all you wanna do is modify this visible text `[contains(.,'Prev Close')]` to satisfy your need.

```
<?php
function get_content($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $htmlContent = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $dom = @DOMDocument::loadHTML($htmlContent);
    $xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $prevClose = $xp->query("//span[contains(.,'Prev Close')]/following-sibling::span")->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $Open = $xp->query("//span[contains(.,'Open')]/following-sibling::span")->item(0)->nodeValue;

    echo "PrevClose: $prevClose". '<br/>';
    echo "Open: $Open";
}
$link = "https://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/overview/AAPL.O"; 
get_content($link);
?>
```